# python re to match either underscore or hyphen in string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Below is code:

```
import re
a = "safe-Zoned-area"
b = "Safe-zoned-Area"
print(re.search(a, b, re.IGNORECASE))
c = "safe_Zoned-area"
d = "Safe-zoned-Area"
print(re.search(c, d, re.IGNORECASE))
```

I am able to match case sensitive strings in my first print statement.

user will provide input in above code,   Assume it is  variable d in above code example,

sometime user enter safe_zoned-area. some users will enter Safe_Zoned_Area.

The point here is we should match either user enter underscore or hyphen between safe and zoned and zoned and area.

Note: These are the variables in pattern and text.

d = defined by me
c = get from user input

Please help.

Comment: Replace `-` with `[-_]`

Comment: Your question is not clear: how are the patterns written? Manually, at design time, or is it some user input? What are other possible scenarios? If the first separator is a hyphen, should the second also be a hyphen?

Comment: `pattern = "safe(-|_)zoned(-|_)area"`. Then `re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: So, the regex is hard-coded. Then my first comment is correct. I just do not understand why you have identical `b` and `d` variables. See http://ideone.com/LUuhE7

Comment: @wiktor yes your first comment is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Define your regex as

```
r"Safe[-_]zoned[-_]Area"
```

Here, a `[-_]` **character class** will match either `-` or `_`.

See a [Python test](http://ideone.com/LUuhE7):

```
import re
ss = [ "safe-Zoned-area","safe_Zoned-area","safe-Zoned_area"]
rx = r"Safe[-_]zoned[-_]Area"
print([re.search(rx, s, re.IGNORECASE) for s in ss])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

c = "safe_Zoned-area"
d = "Safe-zoned-Area"
print(re.search(d,c.replace('_','-'), re.IGNORECASE))
c = "safe-Zoned-area"
d = "Safe[-_]zoned[-_]Area"
print(re.search(d,c, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Comment: @Manoj, could you please explain print(re.search(d,c.replace('_','-'), re.IGNORECASE))

Comment: @asteroid4u instead of  replacing all '-' with '[ -_ ]' we replace all '_' with '-'

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting any result for the following:

```
z=re.search(r'\w+\wAPP_ROLES\.\w+',text)
```

whereas I am getting the output for the following:

```
z=re.search(r'\w+\wROLES\.\w+',text) as APP_ROLES. Can anyone tell me what should I change in the first code. I need to put only APP_ROLES from the text.
```